# Angular $watch: TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have this `$watch` which applies a filter to a date format:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return pn.myObj.birthDate;
},function(n,o){
    var dateView = $filter('date')(pn.myObj.birthDate,'yyyy-MM-dd');
    pn.myObj.birthDate = dateView;
});
```

The first time i load the page I read in console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'birthDate' of undefined

How can I prevent problems arising in `$watch` when my object is `undefined`?

Comment: change return statemant to `pn.myObj && pn.myObj.birthDate`

Answer (score 8):

Your object isn't initialize at the time the $watch function is called. Check that it exists before attempting to access one of it's properties.

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return pn && pn.myObj && pn.myObj.birthDate;
}
```

Comment: I read the same error in console, but now is triggered at line `var dateView = $filter('date')(pn.myObj.birthDate,'yyyy-MM-dd');`

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you do proper error handling,

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
        if(angular.isDefined(pn.myObj) && angular.isDefined(pn.myObj.birthDate)) {
          return pn.myObj.birthDate;
        }
    },function(n,o){
        if(n != null) {
           var dateView = $filter('date')(n,'yyyy-MM-dd');
           pn.myObj.birthDate = dateView;
        }
    });
```

you can also add to the callback,

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return pn.myObj.birthDate;
},function(n,o){
    if(n != o) {
       var dateView = $filter('date')(n,'yyyy-MM-dd');
       n = dateView;
    }
});
```

That way, your code won't be executed for every value return.

Comment: Also in this solution, the error is now triggered at line `var dateView = $filter('date')(pn.myObj.birthDate,'yyyy-MM-dd');`

Comment: that's because you are not using the returned results but instead access the object directly.  I edit the results above.

Comment: moreover, just console.log your object and see where it's not defined.  you should actually make sure that your object is initiated on time first.

Comment: I tried your first solution with more attention but now the error is at `pn.myObj.birthDate = dateView;`

Comment: there was a dot missing I noticed :)  try again.

Comment: also evaluate dateView, see if it's actually returning any value.  maybe that's undefined.

Comment: Yep, I had already added the dot but it still not working : ( I think the problem is that `myObj` is setted by another `$watch` monitoring session storage `$scope.$watch(function () { return $window.sessionStorage.getItem('myObj'); }...`. Even if `myObj` is already defined in Session Storage, if I console.log `dateView` I see in log: **(i)** undefined; then the error message **(ii)** _TypeError: Cannot set property 'birthDate' of undefined_; and finally the correct value **(iii)** 1941-04-12

Comment: are u sure the error message is coming from this code?

Comment: Yes I'm. If I remove the watch, the error disappears

Comment: Finally I think I found the problem. In `function(n,o){ ... }` I have to check if n is not null: `if (n != null) { ... } else { //doNothing}`. If you edit your answer, I can accept it : )